# Ckfinder rename image before upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm using `ckfinder` with `ckeditor` in asp.net mvc 5 project. I want to rename images before upload, such as `Image.name = DateTime.Now + Guid.NewGuid()`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i figured out how to solve it. I answered my own question here:
[CKFinder. Rename uploaded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075955/ckfinder-rename-uploaded-files/30697460#30697460)

Answer (score -1):

Uploaded files are delivered to your controller actions either as `HttpPostFiledBase someName`, or as a member of `Request.Files`, your app code will be responsible for looping through these uploads, picking a file name for them, and saving them.

Can you clarify where you are having difficulty?